# In WIX how do you sort a referenced field in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using WIX.

I have created a membersTable that is connected to my MembersListDetails dataset.

MembersListDetails dataset has a field FirstName that is a reference field from members/privateMembersData dataset.

MembersListDetails dataset also has a membersTags field dataset that is a reference field from membersTags dataset it can be filtered.

This all works, however I can't find the code to allow me to sort my membersTable by firstName.

I have found in the WIX documents that WIX can't sort a reference field. But that you can query a reference field

**Code Examples:**

```
import wixData from 'wix-data';

let options = {
    "order": "asc"
};

$w.onReady(function () {
    wixData.queryReferenced("members/privateMembersData", "firstName", options)
    .then((results) => {
        if (results.items.length > 0) {
            let firstItem = results.items[0]; //see item below
        } else {
            // handle case where no matching items found
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        let errorMsg = err;
    });
    });
```

I also tried this:

```
    export function membersListDetails_beforeQuery(query, context) {
    let hookContext = context;  // see below

    let newQuery = wixData.query("#membersListDetails")
    .ascending("firstName", "lastName")
    .find()
    .then( (results) => {
    if(results.items.length > 0) {
      let items = results.items;
      let firstItem = items[0];
      let totalCount = results.totalCount;
      let pageSize = results.pageSize;
      let currentPage = results.currentPage;
      let totalPages = results.totalPages;
      let hasNext = results.hasNext();
      let hasPrev = results.hasPrev();
      let length = results.length;
      //let query = results.query;
    } else {
      // handle case where no matching items found
    }
    } )
    .catch( (error) => {
    let errorMsg = error.message;
    let code = error.code;
    } );

    return newQuery;
    }
```

I don't get any errors but the First Name field never sorts.

Can someone please help me out!!!
Thank you!
Sylvia